# Capistrano Staging Deploy Requires Whole New Database Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, capistrano

I have Capistrano set up such that it allows me to deploy the staging version of my Ruby on Rails website to an amazon server from a git repository successfully. However, after deploying, I **must** run a migration on the database on the server. If I do not, any page with login forms or database-based content cannot load. When I run the migration on the server, I see every singly migration on the site being migrated, not just the most recent ones.

I know that Capistrano can maintain the previous migrations, and I thought it did that automatically. **My question is, how do stop the apparent database wipe or loss which is occurring so that a migration is only needed if there are actually new migrations?**

I see no unusual errors in the Capistrano output and I am a novice when it comes to Capistrano and databases. I noticed that my database.yml file has no entry for staging and I was wondering if it could be as simple as adding an entry for staging with the database set to db/development.sqlite3?

here is my deploy.rb file:

```
set :application, "staging"
set :scm, :git
set :repository, "."
set :deploy_via, :copy
#set :copy_cache, true
set :copy_exclude, [".git"]
set :user, "username"
set :use_sudo, false

default_run_options[:pty] = true

server "server_url", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/staging"

# if you want to clean up old releases on each deploy uncomment this:
set :keep_releases, 3
after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"

# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
     run "touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

And my database.yml file:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capistrano is not the one that maintains your migration number. rails does. If you want capistrano to run the migrations for you as part of deploy, add this to your config/deploy.rb

```
after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:migrate"
```

you should probably have a different location for production sqlite3 file where it will not get rewritten for every deploy, instead of db/production.sqlite3. Something like /home/user/production.sqlite3

Comment: This doesn't quite get to the core of my question. I know I can get cap to run the migration for me, the problem is that it is migrating things that I think should have already been migrated by previous deploys. What is rewriting the production database though? From the database.yml I get the impression that the development database is static (unless you migrate new things to it).

Comment: See the bottom part of my answer. If you have your development.sqlite3 file under db folder, its going to be overwritten everytime you deploy. So it loses its last run migration info. Capistrano creates a new folder for each deploy and symlinks it to current folder.

Comment: I tried changing the directory of development.sqlite3 to /var/www/db and I moved the development.sqlite3 file to that directory, but the issue persists. I do not have a production.sqlite3 file in my db folder. I changed that directory to the same directory as the development even though I have no file for it and that caused rails to fail (couldn't start).

Comment: Sort of figured it out for now. I redirected production to the development.sqlite3 db. (database: /var/www/db/development.sqlite3 instead of databse: /var/www/db/production.sqlite3). I presume this is probably bad practice, but for now when I run cap deploy, I do not need a migration unless I have new database migrations since the last deploy. Thank you Vimsha for pointing me in the right direction.