# Capistrano always rebuilding database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, capistrano

Every time I deploy (`cap production deploy`), I notice that it runs migrations from the beginning (as if my database does not exist). However, after this, I can recreate a user and everything works fine during (so the database does get created). Next time I do `cap production deploy`, I lose all of my data. What’s wrong with my `deploy.rb`?

I’m using Rails 5.

```
server ‘***', port: ***, roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true

set :repo_url,        ‘***.git'
set :application,     ‘***'
set :user,            ‘***'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/***) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord

## Defaults:
# set :scm,           :git
# set :branch,        :master
# set :format,        :pretty
# set :log_level,     :debug
# set :keep_releases, 5

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
# set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  desc "Seed data to the database"
  task :seed => [:set_rails_env] do
    on primary fetch(:migration_role) do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :rake, "db:seed"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart
end

# ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
# kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
# kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure you have the option `:conditionally_migrate` set to `true` in `config/deploy.rb`

From the [source](https://github.com/capistrano/rails#capistranorails):

```
# Defaults to false
# Skip migration if files in db/migrate were not modified
set :conditionally_migrate, true
```

### UPDATE

A more detailed explanation for a similar issue was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173119/capistrano-staging-deploy-requires-whole-new-database-migration). In short, it was suggested to have a different location for production sqlite3 file where it will not get rewritten for every deploy.

Comment: I did this, but it’s still recreating the database every time I deploy.

Comment: I have a feeling this has to do with SQLite. I have another site in production that uses MySQL and I do not have this issue with it.

Comment: If you think so then have a look at this discussion regarding a similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173119/capistrano-staging-deploy-requires-whole-new-database-migration

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I wonder why I didn’t think of this sooner – every time I deploy, it creates a new folder for the current version of the website, which obviously means that the production.sqlite3 file also gets replaced.

So the solution is to set the path of the production database to a file outside the project’s directory.